# Opcache issue preventing drupal commons installation

Tags: drupal, opcache

I posted previously about problems associated with my attempt to install drupal commons on an Amazon cloud server.

The installation failed because of two issues: 1) needed to increase PHP Max Execution Time to 120 and 2) OpCache is installed but is not enough space to successfully install Drupal Commons. Change the capacity to at least 96.

I accessed and changed those configurations in my php.ini file via command line. I made sure that I saved after each modification (control+o), exited (control+x) and restarted apache 2. The PHP max execution changes saved as the error doesn't come up again. But my Opcache don't seem to take hold even though I've changed them (the error still appears). I've tried at least 10 times to redo and re-save the changes but nothing seems to work.

I would appreciate any assistance that anyone can provide.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here I created video how to fix this issue on XAMPP but its pretty much the same on other devices - you just need to update your php.ini file https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SAHCzzk8B8

- Yes and to save file you user Ctrl+S

Hope this will help

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.